# Firebase: ensure data has been committed to the Firebase before running the rest of the script

Tags: javascript, firebase

My *code.js* looks like this:

```
// some code

var myData = "some data";
var database = firebase.database();
var dataPush = database.ref("data").push();
dataPush.set({myData})

// some code to be run ONLY IF data has been committed to Firebase
```

How can I ensure that the data has been successfully committed to Firebase before running the rest of the script? I've heard about something called *promise* but I have no clue how should I use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use a completion listener or the promise resolver for that:

```
var myData = "some data";
var database = firebase.database();
var dataPush = database.ref("data").push();
dataPush.set({myData}).then(function() {
  // the data has been committed
});
```